# SharePoint 2007 and 2010 Training courses in the U.K or online

Tags: 2007, development

Can anyone suggest good training companies that offer SharePoint 2007 and/or 2010 developer training and valued qualifications \ exams for a SharePoint Developer?

I should have mentioned the location UK or online

Comment: In which country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend Combined Knowledge (UK) for training

Answer (score 1):

There is also USPJ Academy, http://www.uspja.com

Answer (score 0):

I recommend NetSystem in Tunisia. May be you can plan for trainings and holidays at the same time. It's summer time .

www.netsystem.com.tn

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Dave, Combined Knowledge would be my 1st choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [USPJ Academy - www.uspja.com](http://www.uspja.com/) as I am currently pursuing a course on SharePoint from them and the learning experience is really great.  In fact the sum total of the collaborative learning which the academy provides is more than the learning from any individual course.

All the best for your learning.